# Sql Server Installation Code Error

Tags: sql-server, installation

My problem is this, I want to Install Sql server 2014 in my Pc but i have a problem with it:

> SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> The SQL Server license agreement cannot be located for the selected edition, SQLBI. This could be a result of corrupted media or the edition being unsupported by the media.
>
> Error code 0x858C001B.

My pc is new, I have not had any previous version of SQL server on this pc.. Do you have a Solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you download the install?  Perhaps try downloading it again.

Comment: Seems like a lot of people have had this problem... [did you search at all?](http://www.google.com/search?q=The+SQL+Server+license+agreement+cannot+be+located)